# FreeRadius accounting altering/updating sessions start times after a day, weeks and in some cases months

Tags: freeradius

This might be a very specific problem or just ignorance from my side, but I don't seem to figure it out.

Within our organization, we have a FreeRadius Accounting system logging sessions from Wi-Fi usage. Our team is responsible for the data analysis of this accounting data.

Recently, we had to dump the Radius Accounting Database and made a freeze frame of it. While doing so we found a weird behavior.

Running the same query before and after the dump (a query that retrieves the total amount of sessions for a single day) gave a different amount. Around a difference of 5-10%.

Looking a bit deeper we discovered that several updates were being issued that altered the start time of sessions after they had been first registered in the accounting database.

We then found that previous data we collected had disparity after weeks or months even (with the discrepancy being around 2-10%).

TLDR:

Does FreeRadius adjust the start times of sessions based on some maintenance? Are WiFi controllers allowed to do this? Is it a bug?

Overal we just want to understand the rationale so we can justify the data and adjust our processing correctly, as currently, we cannot trust the values we collect daily or even weekly on these stats!

Any help or insight would be great!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FreeRADIUS only updates the database as a result of data in an incoming RADIUS packet, using the SQL queries in the local configuration. The only real way to understand this is to look at your SQL queries, and incoming requests (via `radiusd -X`) and see what is making changes to the data. It is possible that the NAS is broken and sending invalid or changing data, or possibly re-using session IDs which overwrite existing records.

It is also possible to configure FreeRADIUS to create a "fake" accounting start entry in the database in `post-auth`, which will then be updated when the real Start packet arrives. If you are doing this then you should check the values that are being written, and also if the session never starts up (or the Start is lost) then bad things might happen.

But in all circumstances the only solution you really have is to look at the debug output and see what is happening and why data is being written in the way that it is. There is nothing in FreeRADIUS that randomly updates the database without being sent that data from the NAS.

Comment: Thanks @Matthew Newton. I expected as much that this won't be a direct issue. I will validate internally with the team responsible for the NAS. I will mark this as correct, as it does answer my question and after doing the analysis come back to give an update!